# Errors when putting a string variable into system()

Tags: c++, string, stream, char

I'm having trouble getting system() to run a command in a string variable.

```
ostringstream convert;
convert << getSeconds(hours);
string seconds = convert.str();    /* converts the output of 'getSeconds()' into
                                      a string and puts it into 'seconds' */

string cmd = "shutdown /s /t " + seconds;

system(cmd);
```

`getSeconds()` just takes an int in hours, converts it into seconds and returns an int in seconds. Everything runs fine, no errors, until it reaches `system(cmd);`. The compiler then spits out this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to
'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'
```

Here are my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: `system(cmd.c_str());`

Comment: Why don't you put it as an answer when it is the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

system takes a C string not a std::string, so you must call the c_str function first.

```
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this has already been answered by comments, but not really explained:

The `system` function is a C function. It does not "understand" C++ style strings. For that, you will need to use the `c_str()` function. In other words, you need `system(cmd.c_str());`.

This applies to a large number of C style functions that are still available in C++, since one of the main features of C++ is that you can still use traditional C-code (for the most part) in C++. So, the same applies to almost any C style function that takes a string - `printf("cmd=%s", cmd.c_str());` would print what your command is.

It would be possibe to write your own wrapper function:

```
int system(const std::string &cmd)
{
   return system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

Now, the rest of your code can use `system` with a regular C++ style string.